# CSS vertical align icon next to block of text inside cell

Tags: html, css

I thought this was gonna be a simple `verical-align:middle` situation but I can't seem to make that work. Maybe i am missing something on a parent element.

Here is a JSfiddle with a visual of my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/5QFAw/

I am trying to vertically align the "remove" x's next each `th b` in the middle.

Im stumped. Ideas?

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly... the `x`s seem to be correctly aligned vertically. Do you mean you want them to always show up to the right of the text? Then you need to make sure the table cell is wide enough so the content doesn't wrap.

Comment: I want to this is be able to support as many columns as necessary, so I can't set a width for each cell. As far as the vertical alignment goes, I want the x's to float in the middle of the space next to the text inside the cell. So for the first cell it would be next to the 2nd line, ect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you think about this?
//jsfiddle.net/5QFAw/2/

Obvious you will need to move those inline styles to the stylesheet

Comment: oh right duh - absolute positioning. Thanks for the fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

If the height of the row is unknown or not fixed, then your best bet is to put the "X" into another `td`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5QFAw/3/